# MongoDB's save() - can be used with Update Operators like $set?

Tags: mongodb

Can I use MongoDB's save() command with update operators like "$set"?

Or save() can be used to "update" - only while replacing all the fields (except the ID)?

Comment: It isn't really designed to do that. It is designed to just "save" the entire document. You could possibly get away with using operators in save (because it effectively sends the document in as the second param to update if it is already there) if you tricked it but I have never tried and the operators would break the document in a insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.

`$set` is an operator of an `update` statement.  Save is syntactic sugar that will insert a document or overwrite an existing document with entire new document.

You are likely looking for an `update` operation with `upsert` option set to true with `$set` and possibly also [`$setOnInsert` operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/).